# Executing a function after the previous function has finished running

Tags: php

I have a function `my_function()` which I need to run 10 times. Right now all 10 functions are running at the same time (asynchronously?). How can the next execution of the function occur after the previous one has finished?

*`my_function` contains `CURL` calls and reading/writing to database tables. I wonder if any of these are running asynchronously*

```
$repetitions = 10;

for($i = 0; $i < $repetitions; $i++) {
    my_function($param);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think they run asynchronously?

Comment: The function first finds a row in the table that has not been visited via CURL, takes its URL and put it into CURL, then updates a column in that row as *visited*. However if I do it as shown in the original post, the same row is read 10 times. This probably means that the CURL ran 10 times before the *not visited* status of the row could be updated to *visited*

Comment: It looks like the function is running async; is the function itself actually written to be atomic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a while loop and call the function within the argument, along with a counter check.  then make sure your function returns true or false when it processes.

```
$repetitions = 10;
$count = 0;

while (my_function($param) && $count < $repetitions) {
    $count++;
}
```

The loop should block until your function returns true and quit when count criteria doesn't return true.

Comment: Just perform your curl call async and don't return true until you get confirmation curl call completed.